# Stop text from wrapping around image

Tags: html, css, margin

I want to stop text from wrapping around image. Is there any way to do this without using `margin`?

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<strong><img style="float: left;" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" height="67" />Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.
    <br />Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.
    <br />Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.
    <br />Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxtv9m9/)**

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. You have a `float: left;` on the image which is exactly what it does--lets text wrap around it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @TylerH http://jsfiddle.net/9rxtv9m9/5/ this is what happens when I don't use float. I want the text to be on the right side of the image

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your text in its own container.

Since your `<img>` is floated to the left, you can use `overflow: hidden` on your newly-added container to achieve no wrapping of the text.

However block elements shouldn't be descendants of `<strong>` elements, you may want to rethink this tag.

```css
img {
    width:100px;
    height:67px;
    float:left;
}
div {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
    <div>
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.<br />
        Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.Text here. Text here.
    </div>
</article>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxtv9m9/4/)

Comment: HTML5 brings some nice new elements that are more appropriate here. How about `article` or `figure` for the `img` and its text, and wrap that text in a `p`. That's what it's for. `strong` makes absolutely zero sense here, especially as you're putting a `div` in it.

Answer (score 5):

Put your img in a wrapper DIV and clear that

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'><img src='..'></div>
text here. text here...
```

[Here's the JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxtv9m9/1/)

Or, simply remove all CSS and put "<br>" after the image:

```
<img src="..."><br>
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxtv9m9/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Using html enter the following code:

<br clear="left">

This works for me using multiple WordPress sites.

-Callahan-

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule here are some best practices to improve your css and html skills:

1) Always **separate images and texts** in the corresponding tags: `<img src="">` for images and `<p>` or `<div>` or `<span>` for texts.

2) As a general rule, separate your content (html) and your style (css) as much as possible.

3) To understand how CSS works you have to **learn the box model**. Here is an excellent article to get you going: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

This box model will help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Using a WordPress plugin

Insert `[clearboth]` in the **Text** editor (won't be removed by the **Visual** editor) with:

1. [ClearBoth](https://wordpress.org/plugins/clearboth/) plugin or
2. [Simple Breaks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-breaks/) plugin.